# Unidirectional MPI_alltoallw performance

Tags: c, fortran, mpi

I have an application where MPI_alltoallw is used unidirectionally, thus some processors are only sending data and other ones are only receiving. The sending procs are always faster and arrive at MPI_alltoallw call first. I was expecting that they also leave immediately after sending the data but this is not happening, probably because the function is very general and it is expecting every proc to send and receive. This is a big problem in my application because I need the sending procs to be much faster. Do you know if there is a way to change this behaviour of the function?

Comment: Is the non-blocking MPI_ialltoallw of any use?

Comment: Or alternatively just use MPI_Isend and corresponding appropriate recvs?

Comment: IIRC, Open MPI does send and receive zero size messages when there is no data to transfer (otherwise this kind of scenario can lead to receivers lagging behind the senders, and hence causing a lot of unexpected messages resulting in all kind of troubles). Also keep in mind `MPI_Alltoallw()` is a collective operation and for example task 1 does not know that task 0 sends nothing to task 2, making optimization such as Bruck algo less efficient than a trivial approach. Bottom line, you might want to try implementing your own `MPI_Alltoallw()` optimized for this scenario.

Comment: MPI_ialltoallw and MPI_Isend are not useful because at some point I need to wait. What I need is not related to non-blocking MPI functions.

Comment: Well MPI_Alltoallw is based upon a two sided protocol that will require some synchronisation between sender and recver whatever you do. Similarly sned and recv. Does the one sided facilities in MPI address what you want to do. It would help if you could provide a short example code for what you plan - I at least am having to do a fair bit of guessing.

Comment: you should never assume a blocking send will return before a matching receive is posted.